# AppBar shadow not being removed, android

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, appbar

I'm working on a android application and I'm trying to remove the shadow under my AppBar, I tried to use `android:elevation="0dp"` but it didn't work for me, I tried `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>` on the style but it didn't work either, here's my code :

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    <style name="MyCheckBox" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#005cb8</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#005cb8</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**activity_bienvenu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="molfix.dev.molfix.Activities.Bvn.BienvenuActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:background="#91d0f0">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_bienvenu"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:weightSum="1"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm using api 25 as target and 19 as minimum, any help?

Comment: Why are you trying to use a Holo theme at that API level? The Toolbar shadow is from the AppCompat / Material themes

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not trying to use that, I just found that solution on other questions solutions, I tried it but it didn't work, I even tried another one using elevation on my xml file, still not working!!

Comment: `android:windowContentOverlay` might be in other questions, but not the same `parent`... Are you sure you're editing the correct theme? For example, res/values-v21 is being used instead

Comment: I tried editing that too but the shadow's always appearing ! @cricket_007

Comment: Please add your manifest to the question  that says which theme you are using and remove all extra values folders that are version dependent

Comment: where should I add my manifest?? I didn't understand what you mean, and what values  should I remove?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151009/discussion-between-mohammed-amin-aimeur-and-cricket-007).

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include all your relevant code, not just some random section of XML that we can't be sure is even used in your app

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to that, all I had to do is to use this:

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```